# Unreal Engine C++ Data Asset Class Woes

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So I'm trying to create a custom Data Asset for use within Unreal Engine. I am super new to this, I focus mostly on art so this C++ is nowhere near my forte although I do have a general understanding of OOP. In any case, my class looks as follows:

```
USTRUCT()
struct FTrainFormations {

    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    FString TrainEntry;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    bool Flipped;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    bool CargoLoaded;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    bool AllowSubstitution;

};

UCLASS(BluePrintType)
class TS2NEW_API UTrainFormation : public UDataAsset
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Train")
    TArray<FTrainFormations> Formation;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Train", DisplayName = "Train Numbering Overrides")
    TArray<int> TrainNumberingOverrides;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Vehicle Substitution")
    float BlockTrainProbability;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Rail Vehicle Information")
    int CommonnessWeighting;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Rail Vehicle Information")
    bool IsSubstitutableUnit;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Rail Vehicle Information")
    bool IsDrivable;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Browse Information", DisplayName = "Friendly Name")
    FString NameProperty;
};
```

Which effectively creates a Data Class as such:

[image: Data Asset]

My question is - how do I change the main array element from saying "4 member" to the value of the first field? So that way when I'm looking at the array later on, I can see the what is further inside the array without having to expand it. I've looked everywhere and can't find anything on this, but than again, I may be looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: Do you know of any already-made class that already shows this sort of "peeking" feature? I'm not ultra-experienced with ue4, but I don't know if this is possible without modifying the editor and/or making an editor plugin.

Comment: [Not sure if this helps but it seems to be in the right direction.](http://kantandev.com/articles/details-panel-customization)

Answer (score 5):

SOLVED: It's actually super easy, just hard to find the answer as no one seems to know about it.

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Train", meta = (TitleProperty = TrainEntry))
TArray<FTrainFormations> Formation;
```

Essentially, you have to use the Metadata specifier "TitleProperty" on the UPROPERTY of the array, and you can set a static title or point it to a variable that will override the "# members". As per the question above, this example assigns it to be the value of the FString *TrainEntry*.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3rYX.png)